# My toplevel window in tkinter is no longer being destroyed. It was working fine until I tried changing other aspects of my function

Tags: image, tkinter, destroy, toplevel

I'm trying to get a popup window to display random text and a picture every time a button is pressed in tkinter. My original code was going to use an `if`/`elif` statement to do this. It worked as intended but I thought it might be easier to pair the data in a dictionary since there would be 50 `elif` statements otherwise (is it frowned upon to use so many? I actually found it easier to read).I was able to get this working but now the toplevel window in tkinter is not being destroyed like it was in the original function. A new `Label` is just being created on top of it and I can't figure out why. The function code is below. Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated!

```
def Add_Gemstone2():
    global Addstone

    #destroy the previous window if there is one.
    try:
        AddStone.destroy()
    except(AttributeError, NameError):
        pass
    #create the window.
    AddStone=Toplevel()
    AddStone.configure(bg='White', height=200, width=325)
    AddStone.geometry('325x180+10+100')

    # add gemstones to list from file.
    gem_stones = open('gemstones.txt')
    all_gem_stones = gem_stones.readlines()
    gemstones = []
    for i in all_gem_stones:
        gemstones.append(i.rstrip())
    # Add pictures to list.
    path = r'C:\Users\Slack\Desktop\PYTHON WORKS\PYTHON GUI PROJECT\gems'
    gempictures = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if '.gif' in file:
                gempictures.append(os.path.join(r, file))
    #create dictionary from lists.
    gemdiction = dict(zip(gemstones, gempictures))
    key, val = random.choice(list(gemdiction.items()))
    # create the labels.
    glbl1 = Label(AddStone, text=key, bg='gold', wraplength=300)
    glbl1.pack()
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(val))
    glbl2 = Label(AddStone, image=image)
    glbl2.image = image
    glbl2.pack()
```

Comment: Should `global Addstone` be `global AddStone` instead?

Comment: Damn...I'm dumb sometimes lol. I changed the global to AddStone and that fixed it. Thanks you sir.

Comment: Also you can just use `key, val = random.choice(list(zip(gemstones, gempictures)))` and don't need to create the `gemdiction`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still trying to learn this stuff and I don't know the best way to do pretty much anything yet..